# SCI on Dragonfly12 Isn't Receiving Data?

Tags: c, bluetooth, serial-port, microcontroller

I have a function to receive a character from the `RxD` pin of my microcontroller.

```
char getchar(void){
    while(!(SCISR1 & SCISR1_RDRF)){   // Wait for Receive Data Register Full Flag
        }

    return SCIDRL;
}
```

I have tried so many different ways to receive something but I am still not able to do it. Does anyone know how to do it? I am sending a letter `'f'` from my tablet to a bluetooth module connected to the SCI port. Everything is wired correctly!

This is the way I initialize the SCI port

```
void init_sc0(void) {
SCIBD=26;       // 9600 bps Dragonfly
SCICR1=0x04;    // Iddle Line type Bit on (Iddle character bit begins after stop bit    
SCICR2=0x0C;    // Enable Transmiter and Receiver
}
```

This is all the code I use. Maybe I am missing something. But this is the only thing professor used to send data so I assumed it should be all I needed to receive data.

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose your problem with the little information you gave us.  How are you configuring your SCI peripheral?  Interrupt?  Interrupt handler?  Too many unknowns.

Comment: oh sorry I'll add more info... do I need to use Interrupt? I am not using any at all.

Comment: You don't necessarily need an interrupt.  I guess that's why you're polling right? `while(!(SCISR1 & SCISR1_RDRF)){}`

Comment: Without investing much time to determine your problem I'll give you some things to check: 1. System clock 2. SCI clock enabled 3. SCI enabled

Comment: alright! I'll check on that! thx for your help!

Comment: I checked on it and it all seems fine. My Baud rate matches the bluetooth module. I tried sending a character to my phone and it worked just fine. I am just unable to receive data, but sending data works fine.

Comment: Did you calculate the baud rate this way? `SCI baud rate = SCI module clock / (16 x BR)`

Comment: yes that is the formula our teacher gave us(also found on the reference manual of dragonfly).. although our teacher had already calculated the value I am using...

Comment: a quick question... is there an easy way to test the RxD pin? the only way I am testing it is by sending the letter 'f' from my bluetooth phone app. I wanted to check in case I am actually sending the byte incorrectly.

Comment: I looked at the SCI user's manual for the Dragonfly12 and it said you can put the Tx/Rx in loopback mode.  You might be able to use this to test the setup.